# I can use my .exe program if I open it trough cmd manually, but I can't if I try to use it from system variables

Tags: c#, windows, cmd, console

I can start my program manually using cmd (when I specify location), however I can't access it from system variables (I have put `myProgram.exe` location to path).

This is how I try to access my file:

```
myProgram getHTML
```

I get error:

> 'myProgramm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

This is sample of a program, that I want to put to system variables.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        switch(args[0])
        {
            case "getHTML":
                getHTMLfunction();
                Console.WriteLine("Prints get HTML function results: ");
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Unknown command...");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I have found my mistake instead of `C:\Users\Evaldas\Desktop` I have entered `C:\Users\Evaldas\Desktop\myProgram.exe`

Comment: In which way have you tried to get this tool into your sys variables?

Comment: Yes I did. I declared my program's location in system variables path.

Comment: Please don't make things up. If you write `myProgram` then the system will not come back with `myProgramm`. If you cannot transcribe the details accurately we have no confidence in anything that you say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'myProgramm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

There's only one way to interpret this. Nothing named `myProgramm` can be found. Which means that the directory where this program lives is not present in the path. Despite your claims otherwise, the directory where this program lives is not in the path. You will likely have made an error somewhere. Please check the path again.

Comment: I have found my mistake instead of C:\Users\Evaldas\Desktop I have entered C:\Users\Evaldas\Desktop\myProgram.exe

Answer (score 0):

If you save the tool to your system variables, you have to give it a name and a value. The value is the path obviously. Restart you computer after saving and start cmd. Type `echo %VarName%` then. It should echo out the path of your tool.

If this works correctly, it is at least saved correctly.

Comment: A restart is not required.. only command prompt instances that you currently have open.

Comment: Problem still persists. When I type echo %myProgram% I get output : %myProgram%, however when I try to use it I get error:'myProgram' is not recognized as an internal or external command ...

Comment: `echo %myProgram%`echoes out "%myProgram%"?? Really? Then there is something wrong with your os I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Check your path from command prompt and see is your folder actually there. Open command prompt and type PATH.

How did you added this folder to PATH? Right click Computer from Explorer and use System Properties/Advanced/Environment Variables/System Variables --> And add your folder to PATH variable.

You have to reopen cmd after changes.